# Java simple recursive function explanation

Tags: java, recursion

So, this is the code:

```
  package rekurzija;


public class exkurzija {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    myMethod(4);

    }
    static void myMethod( int counter)
    {
        if(counter == 0)
            return;
        else
               {
               System.out.println("hello" + counter);
               myMethod(--counter);
               System.out.println(""+counter);
               return;
               }
        } 

}
```

This is the output:

```
hello4
hello3
hello2
hello1
0
1
2
3
```

Now, i tried to understand this, tried googling this problem, but no use. I wasn't able to find what is the deal with this. 
So to be more specific, I understand why this happens:

```
hello4
hello3
hello2
hello1
```

But I definitely do not understand why this happens:

```
0
1
2
3
```

I will be very thankful if anyone could explain why at the end it increments, and why it just doesn't continue to decremment?

Comment: trace it through by hand for myMethod(2) and it should be clear.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I tried, still - I don't understand. Can u please be more specific?

Comment: Well, **first** you subtract the counter, and **then** you output the number...

Comment: To broad for me to explain so that you can be sure about what is gooing on, but basically the first one to exit your recursive call is the one that are at 0, then the other's exit on after each other...

Comment: These kind of doubts can normally be solved using and IDE (like eclipse) and break points, that way you can step trough your code...

Answer (score 4):

Here is the order that the recursion is going through. Each level of indentation indicates a deeper call.

```
myMethod(4)
 . counter is 4
 . print "hello4"
 . counter-- and is now 3
 . myMethod(3)
 . . counter is 3
 . . print "hello3"
 . . counter-- and is now 2
 . . myMethod(2)
 . . . counter is 2
 . . . print "hello2"
 . . . counter -- and is now 1
 . . . myMethod(1)
 . . . . counter is 1
 . . . . print "hello1"
 . . . . counter-- and is now 0
 . . . . myMethod(0)
 . . . . . counter is 0
 . . . . . return
 . . . . print counter "0"
 . . . . return
 . . . print counter "1"
 . . . return
 . . print counter "2"
 . . return
 . print counter "3"
 . return
```

To answer the OP's question, the 0 / 1 / 2 / 3 print at the end because of the line of code:

```
System.out.println(""+counter);
```

Note that this gets called at each level of recursion, which is indicated by the counter.

Comment: I know this. But the question is WHY does it increment? Why doesn't it only show like: 0 0 0 0, or continue to decrement?

Comment: It's not incrementing. Each time myMethod is called it gets a new counter on the stack. Let's just look at a single call to myMethod, say for myMethod(2). Look at the trace above. Circle the lines that have three dots ". . ." in front of them. (You should find 6 lines.) What gets printed out at the three-dot level? Hello2 and 1, but at different times. Between the Hello2 and 1, it will also print Hello1 and 0, but at the four-dot level.

Comment: Another way to explain this is that at the three-dot level, a new counter is created that is initialized to 2 and gets decremented to 1. At the four-dot level, a new counter is created that is initialized to 1 and gets decremented to 0.

Answer (score 3):

Your recursive call:

```
myMethod(--counter);
```

...occurs with code left to execute in the method. So the pending method is then put onto the stack and awaits the recursive calls completions, at which time the methods then complete in reverse order from that in which they were added to the stack. So the first time through the method checks for a zero value and not finding that it them prints "hello4" then that instance of the method goes on the stack while the next instance is called from the `myMethod(--counter);` line. That instance does the same thing with the value of 3, then 2, then 1. At that time the zero value is detected and recursion stops and the code then starts calling back the methods you have been pushing onto the stack because they are not complete, ie: no return instruction has been encountered in them yet, they are sitting there waiting at the instruction:

```
System.out.println(""+counter);
```

THEN your method encounters the last return instruction and is complete.
So if you intended for the "hello4" etc to print but not the bottom part, then the line that says `myMethod(--counter);` should be:

```
return myMethod(--counter);
```

Comment: this part "THEN your method encounters the last return instruction and is complete. So if you intended for the "hello4" etc to print but not the bottom part, then the line that says myMethod(--counter); should be:

return myMethod(--counter);" is not right. Gives an error.

Comment: Yes, you're right: Java doesn't like it when you do that (c++ would have been okay with it). Actually,I would offer a couple of pieces of advice:

First off, the "else" statement is unnecessary. If the zero condition is met then the return statement prevents the subsequent code from being executed, if it is not met then the code will fall through to the System.Out.println anyway.

Therefore, if you didn't want the 0, 1, 2, 3 printed, make myMethod(--counter); the last line in the method. It WILL sit on the stack though, which is why I wanted to include a return in that line.

Answer (score 2):

The way to understand recursion is by unwrapping it.

> ```
> static void myMethod( int counter) {
>     if(counter == 0) {
>         return;
>     }
>     else {
>         System.out.println("hello" + counter);
>         myMethod(--counter);
>         System.out.println(""+counter);
>         return;
>     }
> }
> ```

Above is your original function with formatting fixed.  Before I go any further, I want to simplify it slightly.

```
static void myMethod(int counter) {
    if(counter > 0) {
        System.out.println("hello" + counter);
        counter -= 1;
        myMethod(counter);
        System.out.println(""+counter);
    }
}
```

The logic is simplified, but this method does all of the same things (except it does allow itself to have to wrap all the way around for negatives if a negative input is given).

I've simplified this because I want to unravel it for the case when the original argument given is 2.  We will unwrap the whole stack and make it easy to trace the code through in the order it is executed to see what is going on.

```
int counter2 = 2; // assume we called your method with an argument of 2
if(counter2 > 0) { // it is, it's 2
    System.out.println("hello"+counter2); // "hello2"
    counter2 -= 1;  // counter2 is now 1

    // enter recursive call
    int counter1 = counter2; // the recursive call has a different scope
    if(counter1 > 0) { // it is, it's 1
        System.out.println("hello"+ counter1); // "hello1"
        counter1 -= 1; // counter1 is now 0

        // enter recursive call
        int counter0 = counter1; // the recursive call has a different scope
        if(count0 > 0) { // it is not, do nothing
        }
        // exit recursive call

        System.out.println(""+counter1); // we're still in one layer of recursion, this prints 0
    }
    // exit recursive call

    System.out.println(""+counter2); // this prints 1
}
// exit function
```

This pattern should make it fairly clear.  With 4 as the starting argument, the pattern simply has two more layers of depth.

There are two important things to keep in mind here.

1. Each layer of recursion has its own scope and own set of variables.
2. Any code that exists *after* the recursive call is executed *after* the entire recursive stack is build and returns.

The gist of your method is this:

1. Print `"hello"+counter`.
2. Subtract one from counter.
3. Run `myMethod`.
4. Print `counter`

If we eliminate step three, we're no longer doing anything recursive.  So we'll see something that makes a lot more logical sense more intuitively.  But for each layer of recursion, we have to replace step 3 with steps 1 through 4.  So for one layer of recursion, the order of steps becomes:

- Print `"hello"+counter`.
- Subtract one from counter.

  1. Print `"hello"+counter`.
  2. Subtract one from counter.
  3. Run `myMethod`.
  4. Print `counter`
- Print `counter`

To add another layer, we once again replace step 3 with steps 1-4.

- Print `"hello"+counter`.
- Subtract one from counter.

  - Print `"hello"+counter`.
  - Subtract one from counter.

    1. Print `"hello"+counter`.
    2. Subtract one from counter.
    3. Run `myMethod`.
    4. Print `counter`
  - Print `counter`
- Print `counter`

And this pattern repeats becoming more and more nested until you either hit your base case (counter == 0) or eventually suffer a stack overflow exception.

When we hit the base case, step 3 looks like this:

- Print `"hello"+counter`.
- Subtract one from counter.

  - Print `"hello"+counter`.
  - Subtract one from counter.

    1. Print `"hello"+counter`.
    2. Subtract one from counter.
    3. Do nothing.
    4. Print `counter`
  - Print `counter`
- Print `counter`

Comment: I know this. But the question is WHY does it increment? Why doesn't it only show like: 0 0 0 0, or continue to decrement?

Comment: Did you look at the unraveled code sample?  If you can't understand the unraveled code sample I showed you, I'm afraid I don't know how to help you...

Comment: You haven't explained why does it increment. You have explained how does it work, and nothing else. My question is simple:
Why does it increment?

Comment: Walk your way through the unraveled code sample and read the comments there.  The explanation is fully there.  All that's left is reading & comprehending.  Note that I also called the counters by names like `counter2` and `counter1` and `counter0` to make it more clear we're dealing with different variables, different levels of scope.  And the unraveled code sample places the code in the exact order it actually executes in.